# Does code written in IronPython work in IDLE

Tags: python, ironpython, python-idle

I am trying to choose an IDE for Python. I like IronPython and want to inquire if the code written in IronPython can run in a normal Python shell like IDLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Python code should work cross-platform, cross-IDE as at heart they all use the same interpreter (although versions may differ). Your IDE should only edit and run programs and will not affect the code you write.